# A QuerySet by aggregate field value

Tags: python, django, database

Let's say I have the following model:

```
class Contest:
    title = models.CharField( max_length = 200 )
    description = models.TextField()

class Image:
    title = models.CharField( max_length = 200 )
    description = models.TextField()
    contest = models.ForeignKey( Contest )
    user = models.ForeignKey( User )

    def score( self ):
        return self.vote_set.all().aggregate( models.Sum( 'value' ) )[ 'value__sum' ]

class Vote:
    value = models.SmallIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey( User )
    image = models.ForeignKey( Image )
```

The users of a site can contribute their images to several contests. Then other users can vote them up or down.

Everything works fine, but now I want to display a page on which users can see all contributions to a certain contest. The images shall be ordered by their score.
Therefore I have tried the following:

```
Contest.objects.get( pk = id ).image_set.order_by( 'score' )
```

As I feared it doesn't work since `'score'` is no database field that could be used in queries.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Oh, of course I forget about new aggregation support in Django and its `annotate` functionality.

So query may look like this:

```
Contest.objects.get(pk=id).image_set.annotate(score=Sum('vote__value')).order_by( 'score' )
```

Comment: I'm getting the results out of order... they're mostly in order, but some of them are misplaced... what could cause that?

Comment: This is the solution only for that specific case, and not for the question title: "QuerySet order by method". This is NOT the solution to order a queryset by method: @S.Lott response is the right solution for the generic case

Answer (score 9):

You can write your own sort in Python very simply.

```
def getScore( anObject ):
    return anObject.score()
objects= list(Contest.objects.get( pk = id ).image_set)
objects.sort( key=getScore )
```

This works nicely because we sorted the list, which we're going to provide to the template.

Comment: Yes, you can. You just do the sum as part of the query.

Comment: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'sort'
:(

Comment: @okoman... that means you didn't convert to a list using the list() function

Comment: I don't know why this is getting downvoted.  It happens to be in this case that you can sort by aggregating a certain column in the query, but generally if you have anything more complex, you are SOL.  This solution works fine, though it's pretty expensive...

Answer (score 2):

The db-level `order_by` cannot sort queryset by model's python method.

The solution is to introduce `score` field to `Image` model and recalculate it on every `Vote` update. Some sort of denormalization. When you will can to sort by it.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the *best* solution, but it is *a* solution.