# how to sort by a computed value in django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, sorting, django-models

Hey I want to sort objects based on a computed value in django... how do I do it?

Here is an example User profile model based on stack overflow that explains my predicament:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def get_reputation():
        ... 
        return reputation
    reputation = property(get_reputation)
```

So, say I want to sort users by reputation. How do I do that? I know you can't just do this:

```
Profile.objects.order_by("-reputation")
```

Thanks for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to do the sorting in the database (because you have lots of records, and need to e.g. paginate them), the only real option is to turn reputation into a denormalized field (e.g. updated in an overridden `save()` method on the model).

Comment: I decided to use the post-save signal rather than overriding save()... are there any potential gotchas I should know about with that approach?

Comment: If you want to use signals, I'd recommend pre_save rather than post_save.  To keep a denormalized field up to date with post_save means you have to do two UPDATE queries where one would suffice.

Comment: @Carl Meyer Thanks Carl... I'm actually updating a different model than the one that's being saved, but thanks... I think the rule of thumb is use post-save to update a different model from the one you're saving, and pre-save if it's the same model, no?

Comment: @Jim Robert Sure, in that case you want post_save to ensure you only do the update if the model successfully saved.

Answer (score 16):

Since your calculation code exists only within Python, you have to perform the sorting in Python as well:

```
sorted (Profile.objects.all (), key = lambda p: p.reputation)
```

Comment: hey, this is the answer to the question I asked, but I accepted the other one because it solved the problem I have... specifically S.Lott's comment. I upmodded your answer though :)

Comment: is there a way to make this return a queryset instead of a regular python list (or convert a list to a queryset)?

Comment: That seems like a bit heavy to ask in a comment, so I moved it to it's own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058135/django-convert-a-list-back-to-a-queryset

Answer (score 7):

As of Django-1.8, it is possible to sort a QuerySet using [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/) as long as the computed value can be rendered in SQL. You can also use [`annotations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by) to the model as the [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) term.

```
from django.db.models import F
Profile.objects.annotate(reputation=(F('<field>') + ...)).order_by("-reputation")
```

Basic operations like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `**` can be used with `F()`. In addition there are several other functions such as `Count`, `Avg`, `Max`, ...

Links:

- [Aggregation - `order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by)
- [Making Queries - filters can reference fields on a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)
- [Query Expressions - Built in Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#built-in-expressions)

See also this SO Q&A: [Order a QuerySet by aggregate field value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476033/1020470)