# Django ORM and hitting DB

Tags: django, orm

When I do something like

I. `objects = Model.objects.all()`

and then

II. `objects.filter(field_1=some_condition)`

I hit db every time when on the step 2 with various conditions. Is there any way to get all data in first action and then just take care of the result?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You actually don't hit the db until you evaluate the qs, queries are [**`lazy`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Read more [**`here`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

edit:

After re-reading your question it becomes apparent you were asking how to prevent db hits when filtering for different conditions.

```
qs = SomeModel.objects.all()

qs1 = qs.filter(some_field='some_value')
qs2 = qs.filter(some_field='some_other_value')
```

Usually you would want the database to do the filtering for you.

You could force an evaluation of the qs by converting it to a list. This would prevent further db hits, however it would likely be worse than having your db return you results.

```
qs_l = list(qs)
qs1_l = [element for element in qs_l if element.some_field='some_value']
qs2_l = [element for element in qs_l if element.some_field='some_other_value']
```

Comment: Thank's one more question. Can I hit db without converting QuerySet to a list? Or maybe I can convert list back to a QuerySet?

Comment: You can't convert list to queryset. You can hit db several ways, they are listed in the second link of DTing's answer.

Comment: You can hit the db by the methods mentioned in the "Read more here" link, e.g. iterating, slicing with partitions, etc. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058135/django-convert-a-list-back-to-a-queryset/1058152#1058152 and the related question might be of interest to you.

Comment: how to know i am hitting db with my queries?

Comment: django_debug_toolbar will help you to identify db hits

Answer (score 2):

Of course you will hit db every time. `filter()` transforms to SQL statement which is executed by your db, you can't `filter` without hitting it. So you can retrieve all the objects you need with `values()` or `list(Model.objects.all())` and, as zeekay suggested, use Python expressions (like list comprehensions) for additional filtering.

Comment: that is not true. check the links in the answer up there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5989752/4213969

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do `objs = Model.objects.filter(field=condition)`? That said, once the SQL query is executed you can use Python expressions to do further filtering/processing without incurring additional database hits.