# Add an element to a queryset

Tags: django, django-models

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [django - convert a list back to a queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058135/django-convert-a-list-back-to-a-queryset)

I try to add an element to an empty query_set I created. Here is what I did:

```
      query_set=User.objects.none()
      for user in list:
          query_set=query_set | user
```

where "list" is a list of users.

I get this error message: 'User' object has no attribute '_clone'

Comment: What are you trying to do? Filter with that user?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
  filter = models.Q(user=User.objects.none())
  for user in list:
      filter |= models.Q(user=user)

  #Returns mymodel instances filter for users in list or none
  query_set = mymodel.objects.filter(filter)
```