# Django Listview sorting by object method and returning Python list as queryset

Tags: python, django, listview, sorting

I have a Django generic view (ListView) and I would like to add options to order the objects by its methods which are slightly complex and perhaps unwieldy to implement with something like `extra()`. I realize the only way to do this is to sort() the Queryset with something like this:

```
sorted(queryset, key=lambda q: q.choice_entropy())
```

However, to incorporate this in ListView, and also allow users to select the ordering criteria, I would require something like this

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Question

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(IndexView, self).get_queryset()
        if 'order_by' in self.request.GET:
            if self.request.GET['order_by'] == 'entropy':
                return sorted(queryset, key=lambda q: q.choice_entropy())
            elif self.request.GET['order_by'] == 'newest':
                return queryset.order_by('-published_time')
            elif self.request.GET['order_by'] == ... (some other sorting criterion)
        return queryset
```

The problem here (presumably) is that `sorted(queryset, key=lambda q: q.choice_entropy())` returns a `<type 'list'>` while `queryset` is of type `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`.

I didn't think this would be a problem since [`self.queryset` can actually be any iterable of items, not just a queryset.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L196) but ListView doesn't seem to like this and I simply get `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.` and the following traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 80, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 56, in resolve_template
    return loader.select_template(template)
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 184, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist("No template names provided")
TemplateDoesNotExist: No template names provided
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 69, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 297, in get_traceback_html
    c = Context(self.get_traceback_data())
  File "/Users/zazapachulia/.virtualenvs/qandapp-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 237, in get_traceback_data
    for loader in template_source_loaders:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I am unable to glean from this what exactly the `NoneType` here is as I've tested the sort in a custom `manage.py` command and gotten sorted and albeit Python list results so I don't really believe that it has to do with the object type.

Could be something blatantly obvious I seem to be missing. Any ideas?

I've looked into trying to cast the `list` back into a `QuerySet` but supposedly [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058135/django-convert-a-list-back-to-a-queryset).

I guess failing to debug the above, the question becomes, how can I modify the view to not require a queryset object and just use the list which supposedly shouldn't care whether it's a queryset or a list.

Comment: Try checking `queryset` value before returning it. Like `if queryset: print('exist!')`

Comment: `queryset` is definitely not a `NoneType`.

Comment: Sorry about that. You're right.

Comment: Are you using {% for obj in object_list %} in your question_list.html template?