# Django combine two fields data into a queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model say Club where we have fields like:

```
manager = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name="return_manager", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
members = models.ManyToManyField(Users, related_name="return_members", blank=True)
```

Now I want to create a drop down in a form where I can add both the manager and members to it. I tried making two requests for `Club.objects.filter(pk=mypk).members.all()` and `Club.objects.filter(pk=mypk).manager`. I tried chain function and using '| ' operator but none worked. I think the manager is a single User and not a queryset, that is what the main problem is. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way getting all of the information together involves modifying your [form choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).

In your view you would need to pass the choices along as context to your form.

```
def my_view(request, club_pk):
    context = {}
    context.update({
        "manager": Club.objects.get(pk=club_pk).manager,
        "members": Club.objects.get(pk=club_pk).members.all()
    }
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None, request=request, context=context)
```

In your form, you would need to modify the `__init__` method to update your choices like so:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    all_club_members = forms.ChoiceField('Manager + Members', required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context = kwargs.pop('context', None)

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        manager_tuple = [(self.context['manager'].id, self.context['manager'].display_name)]
        members_tuples = [(member.id, member.display_name) for member in self.context['members']
        self.fields['all_club_members'].choices = manager_tuple + members_tuples
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
manager = [Club.objects.filter(pk=mypk).manager]
members = Club.objects.filter(pk=mypk).members.all()
userlist = list(manager) + list(members)
return Users.objects.filter(pk__in=userlist)
```

Should create a queryset of all users

Comment: I have to return a queryset only. Am overriding the get_queryset method.

Comment: You now have a list of users, you can return a query set of all the user id's using `Users.objects.filter(pk__in=userlist)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058135/django-convert-a-list-back-to-a-queryset