# django - ordering queryset by a calculated field

Tags: django

I want to have a model with calculated fields that I can apply sorting on. For example, let's say that I have the following model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    A = models.IntegerField(..)
    B = models.IntegerField(..)
    C = models.ForeignKey(..)
```

I want to have a D and an E field that are calculated by the following formulas:

1. D = A - B
2. E = A - X (where X is a field of the relevant record of model C)

Implementing this would be trivial if I didn't need to apply sorting; I would just add properties to the model class.  However, I need ordering by these fields.

A solution is to fetch all records into memory and do the sorting there, which I conceive  a last resort (it will break things regarding pagination).

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying? Any guidance is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Denormalization is a no-go. The value of field X changes very frequently and a lot of Foo records are related to one record of model C. An update of X will require thousands of updates of E.

Comment: Just to point out that a similar question has been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930865/how-to-sort-by-a-computed-value-in-django

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would take a look at the [**extra**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method on Queryset and specify the **order_by** parameter.

Comment: Unless D and E are materialized in the database, I don't see how the extra(order_by) is going to help.

Comment: @celopes sql's order by works with on-the-fly calculated fields, therefore extra method is suitable here.

Comment: Please don't rely on `extra()` for this as it's meant to be deprecated.

Answer (score 31):

If you would not mind some logic duplicaton, then the following will work:

```
Foo.objects.extra(select={'d_field': 'A - B'}).extra(order_by=['d_field'])
```

Comment: if you need to pass parameters, you should use OrderedDict: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: Please don't rely on `extra()` for this as it's meant to be deprecated.

Comment: `Foo.objects.extra(select={'d_field': 'A - B'}, order_by=['d_field'])` one `extra`
is enough

Answer (score 31):

Please refrain from using `extra()` as it's meant to be deprecated in the future.

Since Django 1.7 you can use a combination of `annotate()` and `order_by()` to achieve this

```
Foo.objects.annotate(ordering=F('A') - F('B')).order_by('ordering')
```

There's also ungoing work to allow expressions to be used all over the ORM so the following should work in future versions of Django:

```
Foo.objects.order_by(F('A') - F('B'))
```

Answer (score 12):

As [Simon says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37670464/4794), you can now use expressions in queries, and those values will be calculated in the database. Here are the queries you asked about with the new sorting technique:

```
Foo.objects.order_by(F('a') - F('b'))
Foo.objects.order_by(F('a') - F('bar__x'))
```

Here's a complete runnable example that plays with these expressions:

```
# Tested with Django 1.9.2
import logging
import sys

import django
from django.apps import apps
from django.apps.config import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connections, models, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.db.models.functions import Concat, Value

from mock import patch, PropertyMock, MagicMock

NAME = 'udjango'


def main():

    setup()

    class Bar(models.Model):
        x = models.IntegerField()

    class Foo(models.Model):
        a = models.IntegerField()
        b = models.IntegerField()
        bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

    syncdb(Bar)
    syncdb(Foo)

    bar1 = Bar.objects.create(x=1)
    bar5 = Bar.objects.create(x=5)
    Foo.objects.create(a=10, b=3, bar=bar1)
    Foo.objects.create(a=13, b=3, bar=bar5)
    Foo.objects.create(a=15, b=9, bar=bar1)

    print(Foo.objects.annotate(ordering=F('a') - F('b'))
          .order_by('ordering').values_list('a', 'b', 'bar__x', 'ordering'))
    # >>> [(15, 9, 1, 6), (10, 3, 1, 7), (13, 3, 5, 10)]

    print(Foo.objects.annotate(ordering=F('a') - F('bar__x'))
          .order_by('ordering').values_list('a', 'b', 'bar__x', 'ordering'))
    # >>> [(13, 3, 5, 8), (10, 3, 1, 9), (15, 9, 1, 14)]

    print(Foo.objects.order_by(F('a') - F('b')).values_list('a', 'b', 'bar__x'))
    # >>> [(15, 9, 1), (10, 3, 1), (13, 3, 5)]

    print(Foo.objects.order_by(F('a') - F('bar__x')).values_list('a', 'b', 'bar__x'))
    # >>> [(13, 3, 5), (10, 3, 1), (15, 9, 1)]

    logging.info('Done.')


def setup():
    db_file = NAME + '.db'
    with open(db_file, 'w'):
        pass  # wipe the database
    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        DATABASES={
            DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS: {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': db_file}},
        LOGGING={'version': 1,
                 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
                 'formatters': {
                    'debug': {
                        'format': '%(asctime)s[%(levelname)s]'
                                  '%(name)s.%(funcName)s(): %(message)s',
                        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}},
                 'handlers': {
                    'console': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                        'formatter': 'debug'}},
                 'root': {
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'level': 'INFO'},
                 'loggers': {
                    "django.db": {"level": "DEBUG"}}})
    app_config = AppConfig(NAME, sys.modules['__main__'])
    apps.populate([app_config])
    django.setup()
    original_new_func = ModelBase.__new__

    # noinspection PyDecorator
    @staticmethod
    def patched_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' not in attrs:
            class Meta:
                app_label = NAME
            attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return original_new_func(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    ModelBase.__new__ = patched_new


def syncdb(model):
    """ Standard syncdb expects models to be in reliable locations.

    Based on https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.3
    /django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L285
    """
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
    with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(model)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't presently got a Django install running, but I think what you're asking is how to do a custom save, such that D and E are automatically generated.  I don't know what your ForeignKey's return on **unicode** is, so I'm assuming it's not a string and assigning "valueName" as token vlaue for the integer you want to usage.

Anyway, it should go a bit like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    A = models.IntegerField(..)
    B = models.IntegerField(..)
    C = models.ForeignKey(..)
    D = models.IntegerField(..)
    E = models.IntegerField(..)
    def save(self):
        self.D = self.A - self.B
        self.E = self.A - self.C.valueName
        super(Foo, self).save()
```

Anything prior to the last line of that (super()) will be PRE save, anything after is POST.  That's really the most important point there.

Comment: This is OK if shanyu doesn't mind materializing the computed fields in the database.

Comment: Please see my edit, denormalization is not an option. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I find that without the *args and **kwargs in the save method, it returns an error. And as celopes stated, this is only a solution if you don't mind materializing the computed field in the database.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    A = models.IntegerField(..)
    B = models.IntegerField(..)
    C = models.ForeignKey(..)
    D = models.IntegerField(..)
    E = models.IntegerField(..)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.D = self.A - self.B
        self.E = self.A - self.C.X
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["E", "D"]
```