# Ordering by multiplication of several values in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django QuerySet ordering by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926931/django-queryset-ordering-by-expression)

If I had a model with 3 integer fields, a,b,c, is it possible to do an order_by() on the value of a*b*c within the ORM?

Comment: Answered here:<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926931/django-queryset-ordering-by-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although the syntax isn't pretty.

You can do this:

```
YourModel.objects.extra(
    select={'total': 'a * b * c'},
    order_by=['total'],
)
```

Comment: after you use select/extra you can not annotate on that data set, WHY?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Use [`.extra(select=..., order_by=...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra), using the same name for both.