# django - a model field which gets the result of model method

Tags: python, django

I have this model

```
class Home(models.Model):
  ...
  number_female = models.IntegerField()
  number_male = models.IntegerField()
  def all_people(self):
     return self.number_female + self.number_male
  all_members = all_people(self)
```

i am getting: `name 'self' is not defined`.

how can I define a field which gets the result of models method? this `Home` scenario is just an example, i have more complex models, i just wanted to make question clearer.

Comment: You want to save the field in table? If not make the method as property.

Comment: @Rohan, i dont really want to save the field, i am doing this because i cannot filter by model method. if i make the method a property, then can i filter by this method too?

Comment: Why not to do just return number_female + number_male  ??

Comment: @doniyor, I don't think you will be able filter with property. Moreover, I don't think you can filter on non saved field.

Comment: @Rohan yeah thats why i want to save the field before i filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to add a calculated field like `all_members` as a part of your model, then you will have to override the `save` function:

```
class Home(models.Model):
    ...
    all_members = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self):
        all_members = self.all_people()
        super(Home, self).save()
```

Now you can filter by `all_members`. It would be better to use the `@property` decorator for `all_members`, in this case.

Another approach would be to use Django's `extra` method as mentioned in [a different stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652577/django-ordering-queryset-by-a-calculated-field)

Comment: When you add a `Person` to a `Home`, it's not going to update your `all_members` field (unless explicitly told to via a signal) which doesn't feel like very robust design to me.

Comment: @PeteTinkler but what if i resave the home after new person came in?

Answer (score 1):

You still need to define `all_members` as a model field (not as an integer), and then populate it with the desired value when you `save()` the instance.

```
class Home(models.Model):
  ...
  number_female = models.IntegerField()
  number_male = models.IntegerField()
  all_members = models.IntegerField()


  def save(self):
     self.all_members = self.number_female + self.number_male
     super(Home, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Django [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#managers) can be a solution here. Example:

Custom Manager:

```
class CustomFilter(models.Manager):
      def all_people(self):
           return self.number_female + self.number_male
```

Model:

```
 class Home(models.Model):
     ....
     objects= CustomFilter()
```

Views:

```
allpeople= Home.objects.all_people(Home.objects.all())
```

Comment: ``objects.all_people`` returns only number of all people, right? and this for each object of home, right? (i didnot dv, i uvoted)

Comment: `objects.all()` returns a queryset which contains all objects of `Home`. :)

Comment: I have suggested this way because in comments on the question, you said about filtering with model method. Using django managers, you can filter results using the method you design in Managers.