# Order by DateTimeRange field on a django model

Tags: django, postgresql

In my django project, I have a model with a Postgres DateTimeRangeField holding the time lapse between the start and the end of a long task.
Something like this:

```
timespan = DateTimeRangeField()
```

Is it possible to use order_by on the queryset using either the lower or upper attributes of the range field?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? in my opinion, your question is ambiguous. Define sort relation using both attributes. Post some sample data. Why default behaviour don't match your requirements? *Range fields support the standard lookups: lt, gt, lte and gte. These are not particularly helpful - they compare the lower bounds first and then the upper bounds only if necessary. This is also the strategy used to **order by** a range field. It is better to use the specific range comparison operators.*

Comment: If i'm getting it right, [django actually uses `tstzrange`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#datetimerangefield) for that column. [In PostgreSQL, you could use](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) `ORDER BY lower(timespan)` or `upper(timespan)` for what you want, but I don't know if it's possible to express that in django.

Comment: Also, the `ORDER BY range_col` works the same as `ORDER BY lower(range_col), upper(range_col)` in general, if that helps.

Comment: @danihp yeah, I actually didn't read your edited comment before I started to test is out.

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652577/django-ordering-queryset-by-a-calculated-field

Comment: @pozs, yea. I post comment as answer because, In my opinion, it is the answer of the question. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using either the lower or upper attributes of the range field is the `order by` default behaviour. Quoting [DateTimeRangeField django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#datetimerangefield):

> Range fields support the standard lookups: lt, gt, lte and gte. These are not particularly helpful - they **compare the lower bounds first and then the upper bounds** only if necessary. This is also the strategy used to **order by** a range field. It is better to use the specific range comparison operators

Comment: This seems to be the right thing. A simple order_by on the range field itself does order based on the lower, which is good enough for me. Thank you