# Ordering a Django queryset by the returned results of a method

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a queryset of things Bill has worked on like this:

```
test=Things.objects.filter(user='Bill')
```

Now I want to sort all those things by the date they were assigned to bill. Unfortunately the assignment date isn't a field in the **Thing** model. Instead there's a method named **thing_date()** that figures it out and returns the date. For example, the following:

```
Thingobject.thing_date()
```

...returns the date. I guess what I want to do is something like:

```
test=Things.objects.filter(user='Bill').order_by(self__thing_date())
```

...but I know that won't work. Is there another way?

### Update

Not surprisingly other folks have been down this road before. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058135/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If `thing_date()` is a function in python code, you can't get the database to sort on it.  Which means it doesn't make sense to put the queryset.  You'll have to sort the results after you get them into python.  This will be fine so long as you're not dealing with a very large number of objects.

```
qs = Things.objects.filter(user='Bill')
unsorted_results = qs.all()
sorted_results = sorted(unsorted_results, key= lambda t: t.thing_date())
```

If you've got a very large number of `Things` then you'll have to figure some way to get `thing_date` into the database or else you'll have memory issues.

Comment: Well, that gets things in the proper order but it breaks some code further down that's written to work with a queryset. But that's a separate problem. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 16):

see these answers to use a computed value to sort a `QuerySet`:

- [how to sort by a computed value in django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33516286/1020470)
- [Order a QuerySet by aggregate field value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476033/1020470)

Basically if `thing_date()` can be determined using a query expression, then you can use it to annotate and search the query set.

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.utils import timezone
test = Things.objects.filter(user='Bill').annotate(
    thing_date=(F('<date field>') - timezone.now())  # some computation
).order_by('thing_date')
```