# Sort a python Django query with zero always first, then positives, then negatives

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have Django objects set up like:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    count = models.CharField(default="0")
```

So if I have some objects `ex1`, `ex2`, `ex3`, `ex4` that have count of -1, 0, 5, -6 respectively. I want to be able to query the objects and sort them into the order `[0, 5, -6, -1]` where any zeros come first, then positives, then negatives while also going in ascending order for each section. I was thinking about using something like `Example.objects.order_by('count')` but did not find a way to do that with a custom function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931962/ordering-a-django-queryset-by-the-returned-results-of-a-method).

The other route I was looking at was something like below:

```
objs = Example.objects.all()
sorted_objs = sorted(objs, key = lambda o: int(o.count))
```

Is there a way to use the sorted method to sort the  zeros first? I was unable to find one.

The final way I am using is:

```
objs = Example.objects.all()
zero_objs = []
positive_objs = []
negative_objs = []
for obj in objs:
    if obj.count == 0:
        zero_objs.append(obj)
    elif obj.count < 0:
        negative_objs.append(obj)
    else:
        postitive_objs.append(obj)
sorted_objs = zero_objs + sorted(postitive_objs) + sorted(negative_objs)
```

This works but seems like it's not the best way to do this, so any ideas would be great. As a side note, I am aware the count attribute would be better stored as an integer field, but I would like to accomplish this while keeping it a char field.

Comment: Are you looking to do this at the DB level so your query returns the results with that criteria or at the Python level?

Comment: Why is count a CharField? That really complicates things unnecessarily. Make it an IntegerField.

Comment: 'cos something like: `sorted_objs = sorted(Example.objects.all(), lambda obj: (obj.count != 0, obj.count < 0, obj.count))` will do it in Python for you - might not be efficient though depending how big your total objects are though... and won't work on charfields properly as @manassehkatz points out...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) to add a new field for ordering purposes:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When
Example.objects.annotate(
    o=Case(
        When(count=0, then=Value(0)),
        When(count__gt=0, then=Value(1)),
        When(count__lt=0, then=Value(2)),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ),
).order_by('o', 'count')
```

**Explanation:**

Order clause will be composed by both: the "new field", `count`. With "new field" you raise set of rows with count = 0 to top, then set of positive numbers at last set of negatives. The second field, `count`, do the ascending sort for each set.

**Disclaimer:**

Be aware, this is not an index friendly solution! If you need performance, then, just create this new field on model and figure out it before save.