# How to sort by the sum of a related field in Django using class based views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm, django-class-based-views

If I have a model of an Agent that looks like this:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and a related model that looks like this:

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

and a view that looked like this:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class AgentListView(ListView):    
    model = Agent
```

I know that I can adjust the sort order of the agents in the `queryset` and I even know how to sort the agents by the number of deals they have like so:

```
queryset = Agent.objects.all().annotate(uc_count=Count('deal')).order_by('-uc_count')
```

However, I cannot figure out how to sort the deals by the sum of the price of the deals for each agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of the answer that [Greg Kaleka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4338498/greg-kaleka) and the question you asked under his response, this is likely the solution you are looking for:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, When

queryset = Agent.objects.all().annotate(
    deal_total=Sum('deal__price'),
    o=Case(
        When(deal_total__isnull=True, then=0), 
        default=1, 
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('-o', '-deal_total')
```

### Explanation:

What's happening is that the `deal_total` field is adding up the `price` of the `deal`s object but if the `Agent` has no `deal`s to begin with, the sum of the `price`s is `None`. The `When` object is able to assign a value of `0` to the `deal_total`s that would have otherwise been given the value of `None`

Answer (score 2):

Given you already know how to annotate and sort by those annotations, you're 90% of the way there. You just need to use the `Sum` aggregate and follow the relationship backwards.

The [Django docs give this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards):

```
Author.objects.annotate(total_pages=Sum('book__pages'))
```

You should be able to do something similar:

```
queryset = Agent.objects.all().annotate(deal_total=Sum('deal__price')).order_by('-deal_total')
```

My spidy sense is telling me you may need to add a `distinct=True` to the Sum aggregation, but I'm not sure without testing.

Comment: Adding distinc by field else theт ID may no work with some DB's (hello to MySQL)

Comment: This is almost perfect! I'm getting one minor issue, for some reason, the agent objects with a sum of 0 are getting placed higher than the ones with a sum > 0. After that, however, the order of the sum is perfect. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Hm, odd. It looks like [this questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602865/sort-a-python-django-query-with-zero-always-first-then-positives-then-negative) had the same issue.