# Django - ordering a filter by the sum of ForeignKey values?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class User:
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 200 )
    problem_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def points_total(self):
        points_added = PointsAdded.objects.filter(user=self)
        points_total = 0
        for point in points_added:
            points_total += point.points
        return points_total

class PointsAdded:
    points = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey( User )
```

I want to return a list of Users for whom problem_user is False, ordered by the points_total field.

I know that I need to use annotate (as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476017/django-queryset-order-by-method)) but I am a newbie and don't really know how to use it, because the example is slightly different from my case. This doesn't work:

```
leaders = VideoUser.objects.filter(problem_user=False).pointsadded_set. \
                .annotate(points_total=Sum('points__value')) \
                .order_by('points_total')
```

The alternative seems to be to write out the whole of my points_total function inside the annotate() section of the expression above - is that possible?

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do with Django functionality or must I fall back to SQL? Or should I redesign my database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `pointsadded_set`. If I understand your models correctly, this should work:

```
VideoUser.objects.filter(problem_user=False) \
            .annotate(points_total=Sum('pointsadded__points__value')) \
            .order_by('points_total')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that produces a SyntaxError on the second line. I tried using Sum('points') too, but that also gave a SyntaxError. Let me know if you would like the full traceback.

Comment: Sorry, left an extra dot in. Try it now.

Comment: Still no luck, sorry :( That gives me 'FieldError at /leaderboard/
Cannot resolve keyword 'points' into field. Choices are: ' and then a list of the fields from the User field. Looks like it doesn't know it's supposed to use the PointsAdded field...?

Comment: `points_total` is a model method, so it is not accessible from within querysets.

Comment: Sorry, had the `pointsadded` bit in the wrong place. Try it now.