# Django order_by sum of fields

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use the django ORM to order a queryset by the sum of two different fields?

For example, I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Component(models.Model):
    material_cost = CostField()
    labor_cost = CostField()
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
component = Component.objects.order_by(F('material_cost') + F('labor_cost'))[0]
```

But unfortunately, F objects don't seem to work with 'order_by'. Is such a thing possible with django?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476017/django-queryset-order-by-method/476033#476033

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. That method sums a certain field across all related objects. (In that particular example, it sums the value of all related votes.) I need to sum two fields on the original object. Thus, I can't use the Sum aggregator, unless there's a way to use it that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `extra` for this.

```
Component.objects.extra(
    select={'fieldsum':'material_cost + labor_cost'},
    order_by=('fieldsum',)
)
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).

Comment: That doesn't work for me but `Component.objects.extra(select={'fieldsum':'material_cost + labor_cost'}).order_by=('fieldsum')` does.

Comment: These days you should really use `annotate`: `Component.objects.annotate(fieldsum=F('material_cost') + F('labor_cost')).order_by('fieldsum')`

Answer (score 15):

I think it's time to provide better answer. Since django team is considering deprecating [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra), it's better to use `annotate()` with `F()` expression:

```
from django.db.models import F

Component.objects.annotate(fieldsum=F('material_cost') + F('labor_cost')).order_by('fieldsum')
```

see also https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25676

Answer (score 2):

Use extra:

```
Component.objects.extra(select = {'total_cost' : 'material_cost + labor_cost'},
                                   order_by = ['total_cost',])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `F()` expression directly in `order_by` now, your suggested code should work:

```py
component = Component.objects.order_by(F('material_cost') + F('labor_cost'))
```