# django customize `default` order by

Tags: django

I want to order queryset by sum of two fields.
Essentially, I want to change the default sort order of a model like this:(which doesn't work)

```
class Meta:
   ordering = ('-my_property_but_not_field', 'my_another_field')
```

`my_property_but_not_field` will sum up two fields of the model.

I've seen solutions which use:

`extra` : [Django order_by sum of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160798/django-order-by-sum-of-fields)
`annotate` : [Order a QuerySet by aggregate field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476017/django-queryset-order-by-method)
`manager` : [Custom ordering in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883575/custom-ordering-in-django)

With `extra` and `annotate`, I'll have to change every code which needs the new sorting order.

With `manager`, I don't have such a problem.
But I don't know how to emulate the order_by_1, order_by_2.

Comment: Your code does not match your description. That does not either a) order by the sum of those fields or b) even work, since you can't use a non-field in an order call.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes that's the question, I can't use the non-field in `ordering` but how can I achieve the same result using other method? I edited the question a bit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If it suits your usecase, I would simply add the sum as a new field and update it on the model's `save()` and get rid of the property.

Comment: ah that's very doable.. silly me.. although I think original question could wait for another answer