# Django: order by count of filtered foreign key

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

I have two models in Django. First model is `User`, the second model is `Action`. `Action` has foreign key to the `User`. **Basically what I want to do is get users ordered by how many likes (actions) they did.**

I would like to not change the models, because I have another functionality build upon it.

```
class User(models.Model):
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

class Action(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        ("like", "User liked something"),
        ("comment", "User commeted on something"),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    action = models.CharField(max_lenght=20, choices=TYPES)
```

This is how I was thinking to do this:

1. I need to filter the `User` model with some condition, this condition is quite complicated, but for the sake of an example say I want only superusers
2. then I would like to get only like actions from `Action` model for each user, that is only actions which have type equals to the `"like"`. I don't want to filter users here, just filter the actions.
3. I want to group the actions by `user_id` and get their count for each user
4. then I would like to use the count to order the users

This is what I've tried:

```
    users = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
    actions = Action.objects.filter(action="like", user_id__in=users).values('user') \
                            .annotate(action_count=models.Count('user'))
```

No idea what to do next. Maybe something like:

```
users.extra(select={'user_actions': actions}).order_by('user_actions')
```

But this doesn't work and results in `ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["`.

EDIT:

To make  it more clear this is equivalent SQL of what I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
INNER JOIN (SELECT action.user_id, COUNT(action.user_id) as action_count FROM action 
WHERE action.action = "like" GROUP BY action.user_id) as ac
ON user.id = ac.user_id WHERE user.is_superuser = 1 ORDER BY ac.action_count DESC;
```

However I don't want to use SQL, because my condition on the `User` model is extremly complex and includes other joins as well, so it's better to do it using the ORM.

Comment: Have you tried `.order_by('action_count')` ?

Comment: Yes, there is no field `action_count` in the queryset. The last line of my code is parsed by Django, but not the DB as it's not a valid sql. And `user_actions__action_count` isn't possible neither.

Comment: You might read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476017/order-a-queryset-by-aggregate-field-value. You should be able to order on an aggregate.