# Django Admin custom list_filter is not called

Tags: django, django-admin

I've written a custom list filter for my ModelAdmin, using the tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter.
It works fine when taken out of the project into a test environment and fed directly with the filter value. In the actual project however, it shows the filter options but does not change the results when a filter is selected.
What is strange is, the parameter is set to "balance" and the list of lookups defines "positive", "negative", and "settled"; but the respective URL querystring will only ever show `?e=1`. Even if I input the querystring directly (e.g. `?balance=positive`), I'm redirected to `?e=1` and see all objects.
Here's the code:

```
class AccountBalanceFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title           = "Kontostand"
    parameter_name  = "balance"
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (("positive",  "Positiv"),
                ("negative",  "Negativ"),
                ("settled",   "Ausgeglichen"),)
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        filter = self.value()
        if filter is None:
            return queryset
        elif filter == "positive":
            filtered_set = {account for account in queryset if account.get_current_balance() > 0}
        elif filter == "negative":
            filtered_set = {account for account in queryset if account.get_current_balance() < 0}
        elif filter == "settled":
            filtered_set = {account for account in queryset if account.get_current_balance() == 0}
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"The account balance filter only accepts filter values of 'positive', 'negative', or 'settled', but was given '{self.value()}'!")
        return filtered_set
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How have you referenced this filter in the ModelAdmin?

Comment: Yes I have, like this: `class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): [...] list_filter = (AccountBalanceFilter,)`. It even shows up on the page, I can click the different options, the page reloads, but it has no effect. If I pass in value to be filtered by directly, it works fine. So I suspect a problem with the admin's URL construction somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some debugging I found out that the `?e=1` querystring is the admin's way of telling us that there is malformed data... I had expected to see an Exception in such a case.
The problem is actually quite simple: The admin expects a Queryset object, and doesn't understand a regular (Python) set. Since it is impossible to construct a Queryset outside of Django's database API, the solution was to extract the ids from my desired objects and return a Queryset filtered by that id list, like so:

```
[...]
elif filter == "positive":
            filtered_ids = [account.id for account in queryset if account.get_current_balance() > 0]
[...]
return Account.objects.filter(id__in=filtered_ids)
```

That does the job. Now I can also order it as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476017/order-a-queryset-by-aggregate-field-value).